# PESSIMIST_WRITE in Spring boot not restricting read in other sessions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, locking

I am creating a batch program which will pick records having particular status say 'x' from Oracle Database and do some processing and update status to 'y' once processing is successful.

However, there would be multiple instances of same batch running and I have to make sure that no two batches pick same records in 'x' status. I am trying to achieve this by using 'Select ... for Update' in Spring data.

While testing same I can see that the lock is not restricting read in other sessions. I cannot post original code but Pseudo code for same is present below. Any reference to Source using @Lock & @Transactional will be helpful.
++ I am able to see correct query (Select For update) being written in trace logs, but still lock is not acquired.

```
---Starting Pseudo code---
@Controller
class {
@PutMapping
@Transactional
methodCall(){

City city = emMethod(Long id)
//My print statement that data has been selected
sleep thread for 15 sec
//Print statement after sleep
update Method call here
}
}
---End of Controller class
@Repository
Class Repos{
@Autowired 
EntityManager em;

public City emMethod(Long id){
Query q = em.CreateQuery("Select C from City C where id =:id");
q.setParameter("id",id);
**q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)**;
List list = q.getResultList();
return (City) list.get(0);
}

@Modifying
myUpdateMethod(City city){//update body here};

}

}
```

Comment: 'I am able to see correct query (Select For update) being written in trace logs, but still lock is not acquired' how is this a Spring Data issue then?

Comment: @crizzis That's why I have asked, If something is missed and causing everything to work except acquiring lock. Same query from trace if run on sql developer, is not letting my @ Get request return , unless I do explicit commit/ rollback in sql developer session.

Comment: Perhaps `@Transactional` is not respected at all. You could verify that by checking what `TransactionsynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` returns from inside the controller method call